# Prove that inequality is true for every real number

Tags: inequality

How do I prove that for every $ x \in R $ this is true:

$$
\left\lvert 1+x \right\rvert \le \left\lvert 2x-1 \right\rvert + \left\lvert 2-x \right\rvert
$$
 I got no clue how to show it's true for every real number.

Comment: Absolute value signs almost always mean "separate into cases". Have you tried that?

Comment: The main exception to "separate into cases" is when the triangle inequality does the work for us.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint

$$|x + 1| = \left|(2x - 1) + (2-x)\right|$$

Comment: So can I prove this using the triangle inequality?